# Not able to get Csv file using http get method from assets folder in build prod

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the code
i have tried text as any as well as text as text, in local it's working fine
in prod build it's throwing 415 unsupported media type

```
      this.http.get(csvFilePath, {responseType: 'text' as any})
    .toPromise()
    .then((res) => {
      // CSVPATH:any = 'assets/csv/data_references.csv';
      // Success
      console.log('--------------res1',res)
      resolve(res);
    });
    this.http.get(csvFilePath, {responseType: 'text' as 'text'})
    .toPromise()
    .then((res) => {
      // Success
      console.log('--------------res2',res)
      resolve(res);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried with 'text/csv' instead of 'text'?

Comment: You should show more info, what value have csvFilePath, what is the content of 'data_references.csv', what is the exact output of both console logs... The more info you give, the better help you will get. Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in https://stackblitz.com. Finally, I would suggest you to use the more powerfull observables instead promises for treating http calls, but maybe it depends on your preference.

Comment: This might be a setting on the server. E.g. if you host this with IIS, you might need to add the mime type in the settings.

Comment: @MishaMashina tried with 'text/csv' it gave me the  following error ERROR in src/app/shared/services/common-service/common.service.ts:115:37 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '"text/json"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.